# Why TypeOrm advises to create empty object via `new EntityClass()` THEN only pass fields value?

Tags: node.js, performance, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using NestJS (not Next) NodeJS framework

When I'm creating new objects I used to use `new OjbectClass({...fieldsValues})`;

It's great especially when you use transform pipes from `class-transformer`;

Besides this approach is used for entity creating:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#separating-entity-definition

But as far I see in different guides of TypeOrm usage
here: https://typeorm.io/#/ ,
and here: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities .
They show first to create an empty object, then only set fields with values:

```js
const object = new EntityObject();
object.field = 'value';
```

Why? Does it make sense?
Does NodeJS create a redundant hidden class of properties passed via object into Entity Class constructor? If yes - then we can pass coma-separated arguments

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just cause that's how the docs are. Looking at the code for `BaseEntity` it does not look like having a constructor to assign the fields would be a problem